# Two conditions in the same case, one of them check if contains substring in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, conditional-statements, case

I have a post deployment script in my .NET project.

At deployment I want to update some rows based on some conditions.

This is what I have so far:

```
DECLARE @BRANDS NVARCHAR(500) = 'http://example.com/';

UPDATE [ServiceVersion]
SET [ExternalUrl] as = CASE 
        WHEN (
                SELECT [ExternalUrl]
                FROM [ServiceVersion]
                WHERE [GatewayPath] = '/proxy/brands'
                ) != @BRANDS
            THEN @BRANDS
        END
WHERE [GatewayPath] = '/proxy/brands'
```

If the row is not equal to my variable, than it updates it. Else it does nothing.

What I want to do more than that, is to add another condition, like x !=BRAND && string does not contain "abc" update.

But how do you add another condition in a CASE that checks for substring?

Comment: "If the row is not equal to my variable, than it updates it" - since the end result would seem to be that all rows are equal to your variable (either they already were or you just set them), why do any conditional logic at all?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever because there's no sense to update, if it's already up to date

Comment: In my experience, it's only worth optimizing out "unnecessary" updates when you're talking millions of rows or more - is this such a table?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever nope, it's not that kind of a table, actually it will not have more than 100 rows, ever, probably

Comment: so just add ExternalUrl not like '%abc%' to the where clause in your sub select... seems to be what you want, i think. Should have the same results in the outer where clause too

Comment: @SGN why did you add a `SELECT` inside the case when the condition is the same as in the outer query? This will return the same row you are updating. You'll end up modifying *all* rows, whether they need modification or not. Just use `SET ExternalURL=@BRANDS WHERE GateWayPath =  '/proxy/brands' AND ExternalUrl <> @BRANDS`.

Comment: If you have multiple conditions, use multiple UPDATE statements or use OR in the `WHERE` clause and `CASE` in the SET clause. With only 100 rows though, multiple statements will be a LOT cleaner

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thank you for your interest. I just want to update the value if it's not the same as the variable and also if it doesnt contain substring 'abc'

Comment: @SGN then write the appropriate `WHERE` statement. Otherwise you end up modifying even the values that *aren't* changed. `rowversion` columns or change tracking will mark even rows that match the variable as changed

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos a small example parakalo?

Comment: @SGN I posted one, 4 comments back `UPDATE ServiceVersion SET ExternalURL=@BRANDS WHERE GateWayPath = '/proxy/brands' AND ExternalUrl <> @BRANDS`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
DECLARE @BRANDS NVARCHAR(500) = 'http://example.com/';

UPDATE [ServiceVersion]
SET [ExternalUrl] = @BRANDS         
WHERE
      [ExternalUrl] != @BRANDS 
      AND [ExternalUrl] not like '%abc%'
      AND [GatewayPath] = '/proxy/brands'
```

Hope this help!

Comment: Hey, thanks for your interest. But why it can be done something like `CASE 
 WHEN (
   SELECT [ExternalUrl]
   FROM [ServiceVersion]
   WHERE [GatewayPath] = '/proxy/ipcs'
   ) != @IPCS and not like '%abc%'
  THEN @IPCS
 END`

Comment: if the second condition is for the same query yes, you can. I thought that the second condition was referring to a filter of another query.

Comment: Still I get  `Incorrect syntax near like` , don't why cand't be possible

Comment: try : `CASE WHEN ( SELECT [ExternalUrl] FROM [ServiceVersion] WHERE [GatewayPath] = '/proxy/ipcs' ) != @IPCS and not [GatewatPath](if is this field) like '%abc%' THEN @IPCS END`

Comment: Sorry, I am now looking better at the query you are sending, and I do not quite understand what field you want to add the filter to not like% abc% ...

Comment: It is not correct because    {( SELECT [ExternalUrl] FROM [ServiceVersion] WHERE [GatewayPath] = '/proxy/ipcs' )} might be return more than 1 result, so you can't compare with @IPCS. Use NOT EXISTS instead.

Comment: I want to update the value from [ExternalUrl] if it's not the same as the variable and also if it doesnt contain substring 'abc'

Comment: I think you would add some input and output data, it makes your question clearly.